# Error: 'no schema has been selected to create in' even though search_path of schema is set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to postgreSQL. 
After creating user `sahilfile` and conecting to database `pfile`, I had created schema `pschema1`. I have to create table `ptable1` in `pschema1`, for which I applied the required `search_path` syntax. 
However I came across the error mentioned above even though on applying `show search_path;`I'm in `pschema1`. 
How could I resolve this issue? 
 
**Edit**: On using `create table pschema1.ptable1( .. )`, it says `pschema1` does-not exist- even though it's visible in pgadmin III.

Comment: What does psql `\dn` show?

Comment: Says pschema1 and postgres schemas alongwith user.

Answer (score 1):

Try using quotes while using the schema. Using this way, "pschema1".ptable1 works for me.